# Секционирование огромной Mysql таблицы имеет ли смысл?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Имеется таблица **Mysql InnoDB**:

- Таблица содержит 22 колонки, часть из которых могут быть NULL
- Первая колонка **phone** **обязательна** и всегда содержит номер телефона  из
  **10 цифр** (любых).
- Колонка **phone** **не является уникальной** и могут быть несколько разных
  строк, содержащих одинаковый phone
- Таблица **статична** и не предполагает добавлений строк
- Размер таблицы в районе 500 миллионов строк

  Каким образом можно максимально оптимизировать скорость выборки из
  таблицы по **phone**? Поможет ли мне секционирование?

Answer (score 1):

Первый способ оптимизации - это формирование индекса, оптимального для конкретного запроса. Поскольку таблица статическая, в ней можно создать несколько разных индексов, оптимизирующих большинство запросов к таблице - тормозов при изменении-пополнении-удалении от большого количества индексов можно не опасаться. Ускорение ценой повышенного расхода дискового пространства.

Секционирование в данном случае скорее всего не поможет. Во всяком случае эффект от него будет копеечным, на уровне точности измерений. Кроме случаев, когда всё происходит на системе с катастрофическим недостатком ресурсов, в первую очередь памяти под индексный кэш.

Comment: А прямое разделение таблицы на несколько поможет?

Comment: Что партиционирование, что статическое деление - один хрен. Просто то. что при партиционировании делает сервер, ты хочешь сделать вручную... думаешь. у тебя получится лучше? Ну и - если разделить таблицу пополам, это сэкономит тебе одну итерацию по индексу при поиске. Если на 1000 частей - сэкономишь 10 итераций. Ни то, ни другое, устойчиво в бенчмарке не поймать (опять же если только не катастрофический недостаток оперативы).